# Android Studio doesn't see any phone

Tags: android, android-studio, smartphone

I have 2 computers, and both have Android Studio (I installed it yesterday), but only one of them sees my phone. ADB devices also doesn't see it. The developer mode is enabled, SDK is installed, google usb driver is installed, enabling PTP didn't help.

What can I do?

Xiaomi Redmi 4X
Windows 10

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: Depending on your phone and operating system, you might need to install drivers.

Comment: I use windows 10

Comment: I use this universal driver with my xiaomi devices http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are working on Windows. What had helped me once was to install Adb drivers from Intel website. You can follow [this tutorial](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/installing-android-debug-bridge-adb-usb-driver-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

what device are you using? it totally depends on what device you are using, different devices use different drivers to connect and communicate with your computer here is the official OEM (Original Equipment Manufacturer) list of drivers:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb

If you are on a Windows machine here is a list of useful scripts that might also help:

https://github.com/alkathirikhalid/android-window-scripts

Cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

Download pdaNet software in pc install it and then try.

Answer (score 0):

https://adb.clockworkmod.com/
Try this.
Also you may run task manager and kill adb.exe.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether your phone is showing "Usb debugging connected" in notification bar? If it is upgraded to android 7.0, it will show an "N" in the notification bar with details as i mentioned earlier. This message means that your phone is in debugging mode. If its charging and not showing any such notification in bar, that means your data cable is the problem.Connecting phone in mtp will not help at all.
 You can do a quick and dirty fix by pushing the port a little bit up with a toothpick or something (i tried and trust me it works). But that can cause a bit of damage. So I will recommend buying a new data cable. This is the only thing that comes to my mind as you mentioned that developer options are enabled and usb debugging is turned on in developer options right?